# Retraining neural networks after cross validation

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am relatively new to matlab. I am trying to perform 10 fold cross validation for my character recognition project using neural networks. I have created the nn using nprtool.I want to obtain the parameters of the best performing network among the 10 folds and then retrain the network with these parameters. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an array of the same length e.g. 10 that will store an estimate of the error (e.g. mean square or mean absolute error) for each fold and maintain another matrix (rows = 10 and columns = #params) to store the neural network parameters for each fold as well.

Then select the neural network parameters that have the minimum error.

I want to point that this is not the objective of cross validation, as it is mainly used to get an estimate of the testing error when you cannot afford to have an independent testing set (e.g. you have a small dataset)

Also, cross validation can be used to tune the value of some "hyper" parameter that controls the neural network (e.g. number of hidden node) not to get the estimate of the actual neural network weights

Comment: Actually, i want to test some other samples that are not used in this dataset.Since neural networks are trained with different initial values each time they run, i get different accuracy values. That's why i thought i would perform a cross validation to determine the average accuracy and then select the best network from these as my final network to test these new samples. Now, i understood how to get the parameters of best network.But how can i retrain the network with these parameters? I am using train function.

Comment: You have to retrain a whole new model on the entire dataset. Individual models on folds are just here to help you estimate the accuracy of their weights.